# I accidentally hid the native Timer app on my Apple Watch, now I can’t find it an it’s trying to get me to download a busted third party app

Tags: apple-watch

Just got an Apple Watch for Christmas and when I first got it I decided to clean up the app display to minimize clutter. One of the apps I moronically hid was the native Timer app. Now that I realized I needed it, Apple Watch can’t even respond via Siri. When I ask “set a timer for 30 seconds” for example, it tells me I don’t have the Timer app installed and proceeds to lead me to install a busted third party ad supported app called Timer+

How can I reveal hidden native apps again like Timer?

Comment: You should be able to go to the Watch App Store and find the Timer app again.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @fsb No it pulls up the Timer+ as the top result. Not seeing it anywhere on there

Comment: Apple's apps are now pretty far down the list (they changed their search algo recently).  Keep scrolling down and you should see it.  For me it's the 12th app listed.

Comment: @boulder_ruby How far down have you looked? The Apple Timer app is 12th when I search Timer on App Store on the Apple Watch.

Comment: Have you tried a reset?

Comment: @fsb got it. And only able to be downloaded on the Apple Watch itself in my case. Want to make an answer and I’ll mark it as complete? I believe this investigation is worthy of its own SE question